# How to find cause of TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object error

Tags: angularjs

I can seem to figure this one out even with the help of other posts. It is only happening in chrome. The error is coming at

> angular.extend($scope.selectedCompany, $scope.companyId);

```
$scope.companies = {};
$scope.companies = Company.query(function () { });
$scope.selectedCompany = $sessionStorage.$default($scope.companies[1]);
$scope.selectCompany = function () {
    $rootScope.active3 = $scope.companyId;
    angular.extend($scope.selectedCompany, $scope.companyId);

    var id = $rootScope.active3
    $http.get('/api/apiCompany/' + id)
        .success(function (result) {
            $scope.CompanyName = result.CompanyName
            console.log($scope.CompanyName);
        });
};//
```

View

```
<label>Company Name</label>
<select class="form-control" ng-model="companyId" ng-change="selectCompany()"
    ng-options="company.CompanyId as company.CompanyName for company in companies">
    {{company.CompanyName}}
</select>
```

Here is what the return json looks like

> [{"$id":"1","CompanyId":1,"CompanyName":"Black_Elk","Documents":null},{"$id":"2","CompanyId":2,"CompanyName":"Saratoga","Documents":null},{"$id":"3","CompanyId":3,"CompanyName":"Three_Rivers","Documents":null},{"$id":"4","CompanyId":4,"CompanyName":"Transparent_Energy","Documents":null}]

Comment: Could you provide more information on what's in `$scope.selectedCompany` and `$scope.companyId` ? Its most likely that one of these arent objects...

Comment: i posted the view. let me know what else you need. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`angular.extend` expects objects (See [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend)) and it seems like `$scope.companyId` is just a number. So your view should look more like this:

```
<label>Company Name</label>
  <select class="form-control" ng-model="companyId" ng-change="selectCompany()" 
    ng-options="company as company.CompanyName for company in companies">
  {{company.CompanyName}}
</select>
```

Note the change from `company.CompanyId` to just `company`. This should set the `ng-model`: `companyId` (should probably be `company`) to the selected company **object**. See [ng-options doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) for details, paying particular attention to the behavior of the `select as label for value in array` syntax

Hope that helps

Comment: having a issue with the CompanyId being passed back to the controller  error GET http://localhost:55664/api/apiCompany/[object%20Object] 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: ok, well that should now become `$http.get('/api/apiCompany/' + $scope.companyId.CompanyId).sucess(...)` or (as I alluded to above) if you change `$scope.companyId` to `$scope.company`, it's `$http.get('/api/apiCompany/' + $scope.company.CompanyId).sucess(...)`.